# Testing Redux using mockStore and AngularJS 1.5 does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, redux

In the below code (based upon code examples)  'npm test' complains:

**var mockStore = configureStore(middlewares);
      ^ 'mockStore' is defined but never used.**

However, as can be seen actually a variable with the same name is being used

I have added asterisks (** **) to the two rows in which mockStore appears.
The complaints is about the former one

```
describe('tdNiOfferingAction', function () {
  'use strict';
  var tdNiOfferingActions;
  var tdNiOfferingActionTypes;
  beforeEach(function () {
    module('com.td.wealth.sharedRedux');
    var tdReduxUtils = tdReduxUtilsProvider.$get();
    var ReduxThunk = tdReduxUtils.ReduxThunk;
    var middlewares = [ReduxThunk];
    **var mockStore = configureStore(middlewares);**

  describe ('async actions', function(){
    it ('should cancel active orders', function () {
      var expectedActions = [
        { type: tdNiOfferingActionTypes.CANCEL_ACTIVE_ORDER },
        { type: tdNiOfferingActionTypes.CANCEL_ACTIVE_ORDER_FULFILLED}
      ];
      **var store = mockStore({});**
      return store.dispatch(tdNiOfferingActions.cancelActiveOrder().then(function (){
        var actions = store.getActions();
        expect(actions).toEqual(expectedActions);
      } ));
    });
  });
});
```